# Set background to TextView with CompoundDrawable

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, android-background

I need to make a view like this one:

[image: picture]

I already have a `TextView` with `CompoundDrawable` setted by:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
    null,
    null,
    context.getDrawableCompat(R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward),
    null
)
```

And now I just need to add a red circle around `TextView's` text.
Here's my `XML` with red background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
</shape>
```

But because of `CompoundDrawable` arrow the size of my `TextView` increases (text + drawable), so when I add a `android:background` attribute to my `TextView` it applies to the arrow as well.

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to set the background only to text of `TextView` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, but the only solution I've found is to separate the drawable from counter and set background to counter only.